# SubString function in sql server

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I am beginner in database PL/SQL . I am using the substring function for

```
@String  = 'Y1223456883002'
```

in SQL Server like

```
SUBSTRING(@String,LEN(@String),2)
```

to get the last two numbers, but here output is only 2. 
Can someone explain to me how to get the last two numbers with the zero?

Comment: Use SUBSTRING(@String,LEN(@String)-1,2). The second argument specifies the position where to start. You specified the last character.

Comment: Yeah. RTFM. Ramdomly inserting parameters is likely to mix them up.

Comment: @Barry Thanks . Now its working as well as i want. Now its returning with zero.

Answer (score 0):

To get the last 2 characters of a string in SQL Server you should use

```
DECLARE @string varchar(10) = 'Y1223456883002' 
SELECT RIGHT(@string, 2)
```

If you want to use the substring function like you mentioned you should (as @Barry mentioned) use:

```
DECLARE @string varchar(10) = 'Y1223456883002' 
SELECT SUBSTRING(@string, LEN(@string)-2, 2)
```

And another way to do it is by stuffing empty strings in place of the characters before the last 2:

```
DECLARE @string varchar(10) = 'Y1223456883002' 
SELECT STUFF(@string, 1, LEN(@string)-2, '')
```

Performance wise they are all about the same (about 10 seconds for 10 million iterations on my laptop).